# ProgrammingError at /admin/polls/question/

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Переменные

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://0.0.0.0:8000/admin/polls/question/

Django Version: 1.8.3
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'polls')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')
```

Получаю следующие ошибки

```
Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /admin/polls/question/
Exception Value: column polls_question.question_text does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "polls_question"."id", "polls_question"."question_tex...
                                      ^

Trakebask decided not to apply because He does not look nice.
```

Вот эта ошибка возникла в процессе работы с API:

```
from polls.models import Poll, Choice

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: can not import name Poll
```

Снова и снова получаю эти ошибки. Пожалуйста, подскажите, что может быть не так?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: `column polls_question.question_text does not exist` - колонки такой нет; миграции выполняли? `can not import name Poll` - а как мы скажем что не так, если вы не привели содержимое `polls.models`. Там может нет такой модели